# Predict numbers with end-to-end system on concatenated MNIST images using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist

My goal here is to build a neural network model which can predict the numbers present in the image without cropping digits in the image(end-to-end system).

**Dataset** :  concatenated MNIST digits, for [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7p0l.png)

The model which I had built is in this repository : https://github.com/withai/Deep_learning_on_databases/tree/master/concatenated_MNIST

My problem here is that when I train, my model doesn't learn and outputs an accuracy of 42.5% on test data.

Comment: implementation source paper : http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/42241.pdf

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try multiple learning rates?

Comment: @ThomasPinetz Yes, I tried AdamOptimizer, gradient descent with decay with multiple learning rates. you can find the code at the above mentioned repository.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz Do you think the model architecture solves the problem?